# ms-access transfertext not functioning

Tags: ms-access, vba

i have already saved a recent import in data tasks and now i am trying to call it automatically:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "import1", "temp", "C:\Documents and Settings\agordon\Desktop\ACTIVITYEX.csv"
```

the error that i am getting is:

```
the text file specification "import1" does not exist
```

does anyone know what this error means?

Comment: In the MSysIMEXSpecs system table, is there an import spec listed with the SpecName "import1"? If not, you didn't save the import spec. Perhaps you created it in a different database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's expecting the parameter "Import1" to be a [specification name.](http://www.blueclaw-db.com/transfertext-docmd.htm)

If "import1" is not an actual file, then you can just leave this parameter empty and the file should import into table temp (assuming temp is has the same number of fields as your CSV)